# Anychart migration to new version

Tags: xml, anychart

My product currently uses Anychart6 and we are planning to migrate it to version 8.

Currently in our product we are generating xml with all setting and convert it to svg.

While conversion i observed so many xml are either depreciated or changed . For examples nodes are converted to attributes in xml etc.

Also we use template in anychart 6 and i believe that is also depreciated now so finding it difficult to migrate.

is there any documentation specially regarding xml properties changed between versions (6 and 8) ?.

In anychart documentation most example are for JSON not xml.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no direct correlation between AnyChart 6 and AnyChart 8 XML.

You can try to use https://github.com/AnyChart/anychart-v6-to-v7-migration-tool for semi-automatic upgrade to v7 but this tool has not been updated for a long time and will not work for v8.

It is better that you contact AnyChart support team on the official channel and let support engineers assist you with that.

Comment: I will contact anychart support team . Thanks